Exporting a small section of large .tif results in tiny image
I have a world map .tif from which I set a small country section as my window using rasterio. If I export this section as either png or .tif, the image has a small resolution with blurry cells, almost as if compressed. How can the image / geotiff stay high quality when exported?
Selecting a sampling method in src.read did not help.

without seeing your code for reading the image, selecting a section and saving it back, it is pretty much impossible to answer this, as we can't know which part is wrong.
Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your question accordingly.
